# Jspdf how to import a template file

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Is it possible to import a template from external source into jspdf for it to create a pdf document instead of typing cod?

Comment: I was thinking more of a template where my logo, text formatting, and positioning would be predefined. Then I could simply use code to fill in the contents that need to be presented. This way, a technically inclined person could easily edit how the PDF document looks.

Comment: Well i am trying to get something simular to Msword and excel, where you can extract data from excel and create a word doc from a template.  Is it possible to do something similar for pdf. This way a non tech person can even design how they want the document to look like?

Comment: There is possibility of layout changing , so I want to avoid re programming every time. So would be my best option?

Comment: Thanks. This is an example of the work flow I am trying to achieve but this is done on Matlab https://uk.mathworks.com/videos/forms-based-report-generation-using-microsoft-word-templates-119415.html

Comment: Hi, I found the following plugin.

Comment: hi, you are not mentioning what you found